# how to navigate back to the previous app automatically in android

Tags: android, navigation

I have 2 apps installed in the device. I want to invoke app B from app A and take a picture. I am able to do that. My problem is that, after app B tooks picture, I have to manually go back to app A. Is there any way in whcih once appB tooks photogaph, appB should close automatially so that appA can be in the foreground. Please help.

Comment: Both A, B are your apps (you made them all)?

Comment: only app A is mine. App B is inbuilt. But i think you can propose both possibilities.

Comment: If they are separate arbitrary apps, you almost cannot do it automatically. If you mean 2 activies, there is a cure.

Comment: +1 for @TungD.Nguyen, it depends on how B implemented. If B somehow make some callback to called (A's activity) and do some `onActivityResult`, you can resume your A's activity with proper actions. But if B did not support that, then there is no way you can do.

Comment: how can we achieve this if B can be programmed. there will not be any ui controls.B will just take the picture. thats itso when B's task is over, i dnt need B to staty there in the foreground.